# How to test if canvas is filled with given colour?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, jestjs, enzyme, sinon

I have a React component which is rendering canvas element.
Inside of this component I have this method:

```
  renderCanvas(canvas) {
    canvas.fillStyle = this.props.given_colour;
    canvas.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
  }
```

...which is used for creating a coloured layer.

So I have tests for calling functions in my component and for props, and they're working fine, but now I want to have a scenario checking if method above is using proper colour.

For tests I am using jest with enzyme and sinon.
I have prepared this scenario:

```
it("calls to fill canvas with the given colour", () => {
    const canvasSpy = sinon.spy();
    const component = mount(<MyCanvas given_colour="#0000FF" />);

    component.instance().renderCanvas(canvasSpy);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(canvasSpy, "fillStyle");
    sinon.assert.calledWith(canvasSpy, "#0000FF");
    sinon.restore();
  });
```

but I am getting `TypeError: canvas.fillRect is not a function`

I don't know why this is happening and I am not sure about my approach to this scenario in general.

My expectations are to have a scenario which will tell me that my component, in this specific method, is using given colour. But I have no idea how to achieve that.
I'm a Rails dev and I'm new to React. Please, could someone point me what am I doing wrong with this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderCanvas` expects `canvas` to be an object that has methods, while it's a function. Assertions are wrong because `canvasSpy` is asserted to be called with `fillStyle`, while it isn't.

It likely should be:

```
const canvasMock = { fillRect: sinon.spy() };
component.instance().renderCanvas(canvasMock);
expect(canvasMock.fillStyle).to.be("#0000FF");
sinon.assert.calledWith(canvasMock.fillRect, 0, 0, 800, 800);
```

Comment: I applied your hints:
```
    const canvasSpy = sinon.spy();
    const canvasMock = { fillStyle: canvasSpy, fillRect: canvasSpy };
    const component = mount(<MyCanvas />);
    component.setProps({ given_colour: "#0000FF" });
    component.instance().renderCanvas(canvasMock);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(canvasMock.fillStyle, "#0000FF");
```
but I've go this error:
```
AssertError: #0000FF is not a function
      104 |     component.instance().renderCanvas(canvasMock);
    > 105 |     sinon.assert.calledWith(canvasMock.fillStyle, "#0000FF");
          |                  ^
```

Comment: It is fillRect that is supposed to be a method, not fillStyle, I updated the answer. Consider pasting it as is because you accidentally used same `canvasSpy` spy in both properties.